# Install lejos eclipse windows 8.1 new project has errors

Tags: lejos-nxj

I was trying to install lejos on my laptop which has windows 8.1.
I downloaded eclipse 32bit.
I installed lejos plug in in eclipse.
I installed leJOS_EV3_0.9.0-beta_win32_setup.
Now i went to eclipse and created lejos nxt project. The problem that the project has red (!) and when i create a class it has error:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type

```
Unbound classpath container: 'org.lejos.nxt.ldt.LEJOS_LIBRARY_CONTAINER/nxt' in project 'test'  test        Build path  Build Path Problem
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: I also installed the fantom driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after some more research I found a good video which explain how to install lejos on pc correct way. So after combining this video and eclipse install tutorial i was able to create class and run my first program.

Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEFA0DdFhm8.

Tutorial: http://www.lejos.org/nxt/nxj/tutorial/Preliminaries/UsingEclipse.htm